# Opinion on Barrier/Penalty method for box constraints in Optimization

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, constraints

I had the idea to use an additional term in an numerical optimization problem for a box constraint.
It is somewhat a mix between penalty and barrier function and I am wondering what the drawbacks are and would be really happy for alll opinions on it!

For
\begin{align} \min & \; f(x) \\ s.t. & \; a<x<b\end{align}

I had in mind to use:
\begin{align} \\min & \; f(x)+(\frac{2}{b-a}(x-\frac{b+a}{2}))^{2n} \\ & \; x \in \mathbb{R} \end{align}
To me it seems that the solution should approach the solution of the bounded problem if $n$ approaches infinity. (Okay, at $x=a$ and $x=b$ there is a difference)

The advantages I see, compared to classic barrier functions like $-log(x-a)$, is that it is  defined on $\mathbb{R}$ and compared to other penalty functions e.g. $(min(0,x-a))^2$, that it is smooth.

Am I missing something big and do you have any ideas why this is not used (or was I too stupid to find it)?

Comment: What exactly do you need smoothness (in the sense of infinite differentiability) for? The penalty function $\min(0,x-a)^2$ is continuously differentiable; if you want more, you can get $\min(0,x-a)^4$, for example.

Comment: Maybe this is the better solution after all, you are right. 
I just have the feeling that it makes the Costfunction somewhat weird and maybe numerically harder to solve (which one example I did suggests). 
Also I have the issue that the boundaries neccessarily gets violated as long as for $c_r(\min(0,x-a))^2$ $c_r$ is not infinity.
So I am still wondering why my suggestion is not used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This penalty function is not self-concordant for $n>1$, which means that
Newton's method will struggle in practice, see  [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-concordant_function#Self-concordant_functions). To put it another way, there are plenty of possible barrier/penalty functions, which have all kinds of properties (e.g. exact, or smooth, or something else), but not all of them are useful for solving problems numerically.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is really good input that I could not find on my own.
And can anything be said for non Newton methods?
Do you know a resource where these different kinds are discussed? I am having a hard time finding good key words searching for it- as I didn't find "self-concordant" either...

Comment: @Kero:  I honestly do not quite know how to answer this, but I would certainly start by taking a good look at numerical optimization textbooks (I mean no insult here, as you probably have done this).  My gut feeling is that if Newton's method struggles, there is no good reason to expect that something else would cure it.

Comment: Thanks anyways!